# Mini cart not update the data after execute custom action

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.10

I have create a custom module and perform the action using ajax call. I have created the sections.xml and update the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="southlincprotection/Index/Index">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

but it is not working and not updating the minicart item after succesfull ajax execution. can anyone please let me where I am doing mistakes.

Package Name >> Southlinc

Module Name >> Protection

Controller >> Index >> Index.php

I have defined the frontname "southlincprotection" in routes.xml

my Ajax code is below

```
var param = 'quoteid=<?php echo $quoteId; ?>&ajax=1';
    $.ajax({
        showLoader: true,
        url: '<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>southlincprotection',
        data: param,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Comment: In which page are you going to implement this and what is your front name? Is it southlincprotection?

Comment: My frontname is southlincprotection I want to use in my custom action when I tried to execute the Ajax call

Comment: Just try to debug the file which told you I had the same problem I fixed it by debugging :) @Jack

Comment: I have tried with your solution but not getting success. Thanks

Comment: Not getting success means ? You only need to debug the piece of code nothing else, after debugging you get to know that why your code is not working. @Jack

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be the use of capital letter in action. Change it with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="southlincprotection/index/index">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

Firstly make sure that your template is being run and your js is being loaded

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me

Comment: first load your controller in your browser and check if everything is working fine.

Comment: My other things are working fine when I execute my action

Answer (score 2):

The ajax `mini cart updated` code below work for, you can try this.

```
    $.ajax({
                    url: "/southlincprotection/Index/Index",
                    data: {
                        item_id: this.id,
                    },
                    showLoader: true,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log("Message : "+response.success);
                        require([
                           'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
                           'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
                           'ko',
                           'uiComponent',
                           'jquery',
                           'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
                           'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/cache'
                        ], function (customerData, quote, ko, Component,$, defaultTotal, cartCache) {
                            'use strict';
                            var sections = ['cart'];
                            customerData.invalidate(sections);
                            customerData.reload(sections, true);
                            defaultTotal.estimateTotals();
                            cartCache.set('totals',null);
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

add this to the success or complete callback

```
  var sections = ['cart'];
   customerData.invalidate(sections);
   customerData.reload(sections, true)
```

and dont forget to require `'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'`

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The main file responsible to update mini cart is,

`Magento\Customer\view\frontend\web\js\customer-data.js`

in this file, you can find this piece of code,

```
$(document).on('ajaxComplete', function (event, xhr, settings) {
    var sections,
        redirects;

    if (settings.type.match(/post|put|delete/i)) {
        sections = sectionConfig.getAffectedSections(settings.url);

        if (sections) {
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
            redirects = ['redirect', 'backUrl'];

            if (_.isObject(xhr.responseJSON) && !_.isEmpty(_.pick(xhr.responseJSON, redirects))) { //eslint-disable-line
                return;
            }
            customerData.reload(sections, true);
        }
    }
});
```

So, I would suggest debugging only this code in chrome or firefox I am sure you will definitely get the reason.